# How to plot a curve line between points

Tags: r, curve, dotted-line

I'm looking for a function allowing me to draw a curve between my points. Actually, my data are a profile concentration of an element (here Nitrogen), and I need to plot a dotted-line which is curved betwwen points.
So here is a image of what I want to do with R (I made this profile with Excel
[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
Sample <- c(-1, -3, -5, -7, -9, -11, -13, -15, -17, -19, -21, -23, -25, -27, 
            -29, -31, -33, -35, -37)
N <- c(0.14, 0.16, 0.09, 0.09, 0.011, 0.09, 0.10, 0.09, 0.11, 0.11, 0.09, 0.09,
       0.05, 0.09, 0.09, 0.10, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11)
tab <- data.frame(N, Sample)
ggplot(tab,  aes(x=N,  y=Sample,  c(0, 0.16)), pch=17) + 
  geom_path(linetype=3, color='#2980B9',  size = 0.1) +
  geom_point(color='#2980B9',  size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top",  limits=c(0, 0.16)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-40, 0))
```

and Here is the plot I obtain [image]

please can you help me?

Comment: Shouldn't the 5-th element of `N` be `0.11`?  It is now `0.011` which gives the weird result in the plot.  Check your data!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473292/adding-slight-curve-or-bend-in-ggplot-geom-path-to-make-path-easier-to-read?lq=1 -- although that solution looks pretty extensive & leads me to believe there's got to be something easier

Comment: Yeah sur it is 0.11 not 0.011 thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way get smoothed lines instead of straight lines would be to flip `x` and `y` in your aesthetics, then apply `geom_smooth` instead of `geom_path` and then flip the coordinates through `coord_flip`:

```
ggplot(tab, aes(x=Sample, y=N, c(0,0.16)),pch=17) + 
coord_flip() + 
geom_point(color='#2980B9', size = 2) + 
geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE, 
          span = 0.25, linetype=3,color='#2980B9', size = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: @nico remember to accept an answer if it solves your problem.