# How to make geom_path smoothed in a connected scatter plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I would like to make a chart like this:

[image: plot with smoothed path]

But `geom_path()` just connects the points without any transformation.

I know that it's possible to manage it with [spline transformations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473292/adding-slight-curve-or-bend-in-ggplot-geom-path-to-make-path-easier-to-read), but I just wanted an argument like `curvature = 0.1` to make it simple.

Comment: `ggforce::geom_bezier` might be worth a look

Answer (score 8):

It's really not terribly difficult to do this with splines. Instead of a package, you could have a simple function:

```r
smooth_it <- function(x, y, n = 1000, method = "natural") 
{
  t <- seq_along(x)
  new_t <- seq(min(t), max(t), length.out = n)
  new_x <- spline(t, x, xout = new_t, method = method)$y
  new_y <- spline(t, y, xout = new_t, method = method)$y
  data.frame(t = new_t, x = new_x, y = new_y)
}
```

This allows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_path(data = smooth_it(df$x, df$y), size = 1,
             aes(color = factor(LETTERS[floor(t / 4) + 1]),
                 group = factor(floor(t))),
             arrow = arrow(type = "closed", 
                           length = unit(4, "mm"), angle = 30)) +
   theme_light() +
   theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(6)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(12), 
                 y = runif(12), 
                 group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4))
```

Comment: can you try to do this with ggforce? I tried with no success

Comment: No, it uses b splines where there points act as control points, rather than points on the path. I have a couple of different smoothing algorithms I considered adding as stat layers in the `geomtextpath` package - maybe I should include them in the next version. Surprisingly unusual use case though.

Comment: Yeah, but my groups are not symmetrical. Everything goes well, but not the groups :/

Comment: @BrunoMioto if you post some data I could show you how